# Ipykernel in anaconda2 on Linux can't create new virtualenv into Jupyter notebook

Tags: linux, vagrant, jupyter

I am using a Vagrant Ubuntu VM to create a new virtualenv for jupyter notebook. I installed ipykernel and activated the virtualenv by anaconda2.

When I typed the follow command to add the virtualenv to jupyter notebook:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name my-env --display-name "my-env"
```

The error info was as below:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/vagrant/.local/share'
Perhaps you want `sudo` or `--user`?
```

Then, I typed again with "sudo" before the command, the info turned out as:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named ipykernel
```

So, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Additional info: my ipykernel's version is: 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved the problem by myself.

First, you indeed need "sudo" to verify this operation as root. But after this the second problem appeared, "sudo" uses default python path, which is the system built-in python path, NOT your anaconda environment's python path.

All you need is just to set the default python path to the environment's,
with this line of commands as:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python ~/anaconda2/env/my-env/bin/python 1
```

And then, run:

```
sudo python -m ipykernel install --user --name my-env --display-name "my-env"
```